# Isotope not working with async results

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-isotope

Isotope not working with async results

Hello all, I have a layout which displays search results that can be viewed in list (full width) or grid view, the results come in asynchronously, all products are visible but slightly transparent, then when the data comes in from the async request, they need to become fully opaque and move to the top.

I need to animate these, so am implementing [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), all have a data-status attribute of `unavailable`. When they are returned, I change the status to `returned`, and then run the `sort` method which runs Isotop and filters first by the `data-status` (showing the returned first) and then in price order.

It works perfectly locally, with static data, but when I implement into the project with the async results, it just doesn't sort and filter.

Below is an outline of my implementation - if anyone could take a look and see if I am doing something wrong I would be eternally grateful.

**Results object overview:**

```
searchResults = {

    init: function () {
        $('#filter').on("change", searchResults.sort);
    },

    getPrice: function (productId, url) { // called elsewhere to load each product
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: searchResults.priceReturned
        });
    },
    priceReturned: function (data) {
        var container = $(".product[data-productid='" + data.ProductId + "']");

        if (data.Unavailable) {
            container.addClass('unavailable');
            container.find(".failed-notice").html(data.unavailableReason);
        } else {
            container.attr("data-status", "returned"); // default is set to unavailable

            // Process data here

        }

        searchResults.sort();
    },
    sort: function () {
        var $resultsList = $('.results').isotope({
            getSortData: {
              title: '.title',
              price: '.price parseInt',
              returned: '[data-status]'
            },
            sortBy: ['returned', 'price']
        });
    } 
};
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle ??

Comment: do you mean with the solution I have with it working locally?

Comment: it's asp.net ??

Comment: Hey @Diptox, yes it is

Comment: :'( sorry , i can't help you with that , i hate it and can't understand it :'(

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem? and share the actual code

Comment: try to change this : 
success: searchResults.priceReturned
to this :
success: searchResults.priceReturned(data)

Comment: any console errors? have you tried inspecting the data in the debugger to make sure it matches the data you used when it worked?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue in the past too. The Isotope API isn't very clear about how to handle async results. What you'll need to do is to call the `layout` method after you've processed all your data:

```
priceReturned: function (data) {
    var container = $(".product[data-productid='" + data.ProductId + "']");

    if (data.Unavailable) {
        container.addClass('unavailable');
        container.find(".failed-notice").html(data.unavailableReason);
    } else {
        container.attr("data-status", "returned"); // default is set to unavailable

        // Process data here

        // Ask Isotope to lay out the new results.
        $('.results').isotope('layout');

    }
```

You can read more about the 'layout' method [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#layout).

Comment: Le Moi, has my answer helped?